Serve Allure not working in Python even after gnerating reports
I have generated allure reports but when i give a command to serve allure reports, it says batch file or command not recognized. I have added environment path variable and every other plugins have been installed. Can anyone help me out here?
I tried adding Environment path variable in the system
The allure version can also be seen in the cmd prompt
Allure detected in the system
allure reports have been generated but unable to serve
enter image description here

The correct command is allure serve AllureReports

The command is allure serve; not serve allure
